How do I open a new window on top of other windows using a NavigationViewItem?
Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2022, or am I missing something?
I don't know why only using a button opens the window on top like I want it to. Putting a button in the navigation view doesn't look right.
Here is the code that opens the new window on top of all other windows:
<Button x:Name="Tvdb" Foreground="YellowGreen" FontSize="20" Background="Transparent" Click="Tvdb_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE774;" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Text="TheTvdb" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>

private void Tvdb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string target = "https://thetvdb.com";

        Web webPage = new(new Uri(target));
        webPage.Title = "The Tvdb";
        webPage.Activate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Messages.Severity = InfoBarSeverity.Error;
        Messages.Title = "No Item Selected";
        Messages.Message = ex.Message;
        Messages.IsOpen = true;
    }
}

This code open the new window, but behind all other windows:
<NavigationViewItem x:Name="Tvdb" Content="Tvdb" Icon="Globe" Foreground="YellowGreen" FontSize="20" PointerPressed="Tvdb_PointerPressed"/>

private void Tvdb_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            string target = "https://thetvdb.com";
            webPage = new(new Uri(target));
            webPage.Title = "The Tvdb";
            webPage.Activate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Messages.Severity = InfoBarSeverity.Error;
            Messages.Title = "No Item Selected";
            Messages.Message = ex.Message;
            Messages.IsOpen = true;
        }
}

